# Creating a file in android raising an error on older devices

Tags: java, android

I'm currently developing an android application and I need to export a video to internal storage. The code below works perfectly fine , and I was able to export the video , But when I tested my application on older devices Ex: android 5.1 , I got an error telling me that there is no such a file or directory. I hope someone could help me.

My code in java:

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/" + "Videos");

if(!directory.exists()) directory.mkdir();

File videoFile = new File(directory, title+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4");

exportVideo(directory, videoFile, title);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
    ...
    
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

The error message :

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: video.mp4: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) **

Comment: That message does not line up with the code in your question.

Comment: `got an error telling me that there is no such a file or directory.` Well what was it? A directory or a file?

Comment: It was a file,  the video file